# mouse pointer not working properly Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cursor, mouse-pointer

In my Ubuntu 16.04, I can't type because the cursor appears only in the top left of my screen.It doesn't move properly as I type instead moves from right to left.

For example, when type  'help' I get 'pehl' on my screen

How can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the computer? Does this only occur in one particular application? Do you use a mouse, a trackpad, or something else?

Comment: Tried,  and it happens often (not for a particular application ) I don't use external mouse. When scroll down to a webpage, the mouse pointer go back to the top of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I dont have 50 reputation to comment, so I have to write here: I had it once too, it was a graphic driver error. Do you have an Nvidia graphic card? Then you could try install the proprietary drivers and/or updated one.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63692/discussion-on-answer-by-ghostgate-mouse-pointer-not-working-properly-ubuntu-16-0).